# How to make the background white when expanding Woocommerce Product Photo?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

When clicking the product photo to zoom, the first image's background is white. When clicking through the variation images, the background becomes black again.

I've tried setting the following CSS:

`.pswp__container {
    background-color: #ffffff!important
}`

I've also tried:

`.pswp__container, .pswp__zoom-wrap {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
background-color: #ffffff;
}`

With these settings, I get a black wrap on the left of the image. What else can I try to fix this? I'd like a White Cover on the back of all of our product images.

[Website Here](https://www.fralinpickups.com/product/blues-special/)

[image: Actual Results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not to be the `.pswp_container` the problem…

Try this :

```css
.pswp__item{background-color:white}
```